# c# XNA or c++ directX11 in the future?

Tags: c#, c++, xna

I have recently started to learn XNA, and quite enjoy it and it's managed code. However, after doing some reading it seems that for windows 8 and windows 8 phones XNA will not be updated to work with these new features, and that Directx11 will be what's used.

So, does anyone know if this is true? I do not know any c++, but i'm fairly confident with c#, so i would like to stick with XNA but if the future will be using c++ and Directx maybe i should switch over now? Also how much harder is c++ to learn if i know c#?

if the case is that directX is the way of the future, i might just go with unity so i can keep using c#.

Any help with this topic is greatly appreciated, thanks a ton

Comment: Nobody knows about the future. Windows 8 might turn out to be a great success, or it might be the new Vista. What do we know?

Comment: XNA works just fine on Windows 8. However, Windows 8 RT is another story.

Answer (score 2):

At last year's Build conference and other venues, MS's Herb Sutter spoke about it like this (paraphrased):

---

Over the last decade, hardware got more powerful so quickly that we were able to afford the overhead of productive languages like .net. If we pushed the perf limits, so what, next years computers would handle it no sweat. the cost to make software in a managed language was less than native and we had the hardware power to mitigate the managed overhead.

In the coming decade, the hardware used to get things done is getting smaller, mobile, less powerful, more energy efficient. Suddenly code efficiency and performance in the software is increasingly more important. So far native has that edge.

---

I guess since graphics software (games) can be a dev area that hits perf limits quickly, it is understandable that this might be one of the first to undergo this shift.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know(and from information found on the web) windows will move away from XNA, though technically it should be backwards compatible. If you're looking for an article to read up on about the future of XNA:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22292/what-is-the-future-of-xna-in-windows-8-or-how-will-manged-games-be-developed-in

Comment: Thanks! so would you suggest I learn directX and c++?

Comment: It really depends on what you're looking to design. If you want a cross platform game, i would go with OpenGL. If you're looking for a windows specific graphics, directx11 will get the job done. All in all i would argue OpenGL has a lot more uses in the industry being cross platform and easily portable, but that is my own biased opinion.

Comment: I haven't looked into that at all.. I'll give it a look! So is c# for game development pretty much a dud in the future? For some reason c++ frightens me

Comment: @RyanMartin - I have yet to try these myself, but there are supposed to be a few nice C# wrappers for DirectX.

Comment: Look into using [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/), a C# wrapper around the DirectX API. It's updated constantly by the author.

Answer (score 1):

I would stick to C#, you are faster in development and the performance difference is not too much so you don't have to complain over it.

If you wan't to target mobile plattforms too, i would advice to use OpenGL, it's harder to start with it, but you should be able to develop a framework which supports both mobile and desktop plattforms ( using MonoTouch and Monodroid ).

---

**For the people who scream now that DirectX is better:** I know, generally you are right, but DirectX is not supported on mobile plattforms like iOS and Android. There is a [clone](http://monogame.codeplex.com/) of XNA for all plattforms which might be working but i don't know if it will support the new DirectX/OpenGL features.